# Reading gatt protocols in android for Uint32 and 24

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

My Code in Obj C

```
const void *bytes = [data bytes];
    uint16_t napAddVal;
    memcpy(&napAddVal, bytes + 0, 2);
    uint8_t uapAddVal;
    memcpy(&uapAddVal, bytes + 2, 1);
    uint32_t lapAddVal2 = 0;
    memcpy(&lapAddVal2, bytes + 3, 3);
```

I use above code for Bluetooth Address consists of three parts: NAP, UAP and LAP.
Now, I want to do similar thing in android. I manage to do it in parts, I am struggling where bytes is more than 2.

```
      ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
      bb.get(0)
      bb.getShort(1)
      bb.get( ) ??? Not sure for last part
```

Please help what is the best way to do ??
Any help or some other way.. would be great help !!